# DejalActivityView and indicator view errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to integrate dejalactivityview indicator view in my application, and I am running into this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DejalActivityView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in WelcomeMessage.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This library is pretty easy to integrate and I am pretty sure I did everything correctly: added the .m and .h files, my project is ARC enabled and thats how I call the method:

```
[DejalActivityView activityViewForView:self.view];
```

Pretty simple, no? Still doesn't work...thanks for the help!

UPDATE:

I tried this:

```
 DejalActivityView *testvc;
[testvc activityViewForView:self.view];
```

But I am getting an error (before compiling) that "no visible @interface for "DejalActivityView" declares selector 'activityViewForView:self.view'"

[image]

Comment: what does that mean? btw it happens on a few projects of mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's your class name? make sure u spell correctly if again not work then change the class name. cz it some times that your class name matches with some built in name or some method name in project already in use

Comment: which class are you referring to? it's just a view controller (WelcomeMessage.m) where I call this line in some method.

Comment: DejalActivityView try to change name of this class

Comment: to what? sorry, I am really new to iOS SDK, and not sure what you mean...:/ if you could provide some code example I'd really appreciate that :)

Comment: code example is this for example you have an attribute of naming schoolData and u synthesize this, compiler wil generate setSchoolData and getSchoolData but not shown to us. Now if you add a new class nam GetSchoolData then it will generate error like this. that's i'm asking you to change it's name. that may be some compiler generated name is already reserved for this name. got it?

Comment: QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h add this to ur class after addinf framework quartzCore

Comment: talke me after 2 hr on skype: the_saad1

Comment: i'm jst a bit bzy with my client. Sorry 4 tht

Comment: sure...appreciate your help, I am really stuck here...:(

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got the same thing just now. It seems if you simply drag the .m and .h files into your project, the .m file won't be added as source to link to your project, hence the link errors. What solved this for me was adding the DejalActivityView.m source file into the "Compile Sources" section under "Build Phases" of the project target. In other words, go to the Project Navigator and click on the uppermost item, then select the "Build Phases" tab, and then add the .m file to the "Compile Sources" section. Build and run your project again, and this time it should not have the linker errors!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have actually copied the .m and .h files or you are just referencing them. Compiler might not be able to compile these files if you have not copied them to your project folder.

Comment: they are definitely there...I also #include them, so they are definitely there, and there errors prior to compiling.

Answer (score 0):

check this for

```
"no visible @interface for "DejalActivityView" declares selector 'activityViewForView:self.view'"
```

`reply:-` No need for a property for the DejalActivityView

please import this file in your viewcontroller .m

```
#import "DejalActivityView.h"
```

and write this code in viewdidload and check

```
[DejalActivityView activityViewForView:self.view];
```

if you have any error after that implement the download [this from this link](http://www.dejal.com/developer/) and implement , i use and work my code

Comment: now i am getting an "unknown type" error when i do this: DejalActivityView *temp; in the header file.

Comment: I did exactly what you did but still getting the compiler error that I mentioned above...could you provide any other help? any sample app that I can take a look at? I downloaded from your link but it doesn't help so much...

Comment: no need this  DejalActivityView *temp; please direct implement [DejalActivityView activityViewForView:self.view];